# Temporarily prevent hibernation

Tags: 10.04, hibernate, sleep

How can I temporarily prevent Ubuntu from hibernating? Is there a binary available that makes use of an API similar to the one preventing screen savers from activating for hibernation? I'm utilizing a network service provided by my netbook without physically making use of the netbook, so it hibernates after the time specified in the power management preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps 'caffeine' could help? 
https://launchpad.net/caffeine

Comment: Caffeine seems to miss the point, but provides enough to get me writing my own utility. Thanks.